# Replacing every 2nd element in the list

Tags: python

I got a 2 dimensional list:

```
[[5, 80, 2, 57, 5, 97], [2, 78, 2, 56, 6, 62], [5, 34, 3, 54, 6, 5, 2, 58, 5, 61, 5, 16]]
```

In which I need to change every second element to 0, starting from first one. So it should look like this:

```
[[0, 80, 0, 57, 0, 97], [0, 78, 0, 56, 0, 62], [0, 34, 0, 54, 0, 5, 0, 58, 0, 61, 0, 16]]
```

Algorithm I use:

```
for i in tempL: 
    for j, item in enumerate(i):
        if i.index(item) % 2 == 0:
            print('change, index:'),
            print(i.index(item))
            i[j] = 0
        else:
            print('not change, index:'),
            print(i.index(item))
```

But what I get is this:

```
change, index: 0
not change, index: 1
change, index: 2
not change, index: 3
change, index: 4
not change, index: 5
change, index: 0
not change, index: 1
change, index: 2
not change, index: 3
change, index: 4
not change, index: 5
change, index: 0
not change, index: 1
change, index: 2
not change, index: 3
change, index: 4
not change, index: 5
change, index: 6
not change, index: 7
not change, index: 5
not change, index: 9
not change, index: 5
not change, index: 11
[[0, 80, 0, 57, 0, 97], [0, 78, 0, 56, 0, 62], [0, 34, 0, 54, 0, 5, 0, 58, 5, 61, 5, 16]]
```

Some elements are not changed, and it's because (I added index print to see that) it thinks that index of those elements are 7 and 9 for some reason. What can it be, because I am looking for a bug for so long still cannot find..

I double checked, there are not extra spaces or anything in the list.

Comment: Why are you using `i.index`? Don't you mean `j`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your algorithm is correct. You just made a logic error. By using `i.index`, you're searching the inner list for that value every time. That's not only expensive, it's sensitive to duplicate values.

```
for i in tempL: 
    for j, item in enumerate(i):
        # if i.index(item) % 2 == 0: oops
        if j % 2 == 0:
            print('change, index:'),
            print(i.index(item))
            i[j] = 0
        else:
            print('not change, index:'),
            print(i.index(item))
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, this task should be obvious. Use slice assignment! You need to assign an array of zeros, that are half length. To create one, simply multiply single element array with value:

```
for l in tempL: 
    l[::2] = [0] * ((len(l)+1)/2)
```

Or use `repeat` from itertools (unfortunately this is twice slower for small array):

```
from itertools import repeat

for l in tempL: 
    l[::2] = repeat(0,(len(l)+1)/2)
```

Comment: I tried slicing, but didn't figure out how to use it correctly. I also don't really understand second half of your equation at all.

Comment: I was curious and did some timing tests, the first method in this answer is an order of magnitude (plus) faster than the comprehension - and *scales* better with longer sublists.  @estranged - the *advanced* slice assignment on the left-hand-side requires an iterable on the right-hand-side.  The right-hand-side creates a list of zeros with enough items for the assignment.  @Arpegius - I don't think you need the ```+1``` to determine the number of zeros required.

Comment: @wwii Yes, you need `+1` as if there is odd number of elements you need one more the half. If you start from second as `[1::2]`, then  it will be without `+1`.

Comment: A more tautological way to get the length of the slice would be `l[::2] = [0] * len(l[::2])`.

Comment: @kojiro: that creates a whole new list object. Calculating the length is far easier on memory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Since Python has to account for the slice on the LHS of the assignment, I'm suspicious that it makes any difference. [Care to comment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465514/does-reusing-a-list-slice-to-get-length-cost-additional-memory)

Comment: @kojiro: you misunderstood my comment. I posted an answer. This is not about keeping the list in memory, you *still have to create it and allocate memory for it*, however transient.

Answer (score 2):

As a more pythonic way You can just use a list comprehension :

```
>>> l=[[5, 80, 2, 57, 5, 97], [2, 78, 2, 56, 6, 62], [5, 34, 3, 54, 6, 5, 2, 58, 5, 61, 5, 16]]
>>> l=[[t if k%2 else 0 for k,t in enumerate(i)] for i in l]
>>> l
[[0, 80, 0, 57, 0, 97], [0, 78, 0, 56, 0, 62], [0, 34, 0, 54, 0, 5, 0, 58, 0, 61, 0, 16]]
```

Comment: So I just change `l` with my list name? It does not do anything for me, even though your code looks good.

Comment: @estranged i dont see any reason for miss working the code , note that my answer is in shell you need to print it if you write the code in a text editor !!!

Comment: Oh yes, I need to assign list to this! This is very nice.

Comment: @estranged you're welcome ! you dont need to create new list just , assign it to l !

Comment: Or even ```[[t if k%2 else 0 for k,t in enumerate(i)] for i in l]```.  ```k%2``` has a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my two cents:

Using Modulo Operator

```
mylist= [[5, 80, 2, 57, 5, 97], [2, 78, 2, 56, 6, 62], [5, 34, 3, 54, 6, 5, 2, 58, 5, 61, 5, 16]]

for i,n in enumerate(mylist):
    for j,m in enumerate(n):
        if j % 2 == 0:
            mylist[i][j] = 0

print mylist
```

Output:

```
[[0, 80, 0, 57, 0, 97], [0, 78, 0, 56, 0, 62], [0, 34, 0, 54, 0, 5, 0, 58, 0, 61, 0, 16]]
```